# From what location are the 1st computer instructions available on boot up?

Tags: windows-7, boot, boot-camp, bootsector, debootstrap

From what location are the 1st computer instructions available on boot up?

```
A.  ROM BIOS
B.  CPU
C.  boot.ini
D.  CONFIG.SYS
E.  None of the above
```

Comment: What is the point of this question? Please explain exactly what you want to know, this just looks like some multiple-choice question from an exam to me ...

Comment: The correct answer would be microcode on the CPUs ROM. Use Google and don't post questions that look like tests here, please.

Comment: What kind of computer are we talking about?

Answer (score 1):

According to [EngineersGarage](https://www.engineersgarage.com/tutorials/how-computer-pc-boots-up):

> > General Booting sequence comprises of the following steps:
>
> - Turn on the Power button.
> - CPU pins are reset and registers are set to specific value.
> - CPU jump to address of BIOS (0xFFFF0).

So the answer is **B** - **CPU**.

Answer (score -1):

Answer: first A. ROM BIOS, then loaded to B. CPU, to location according to this maybe slightly outdated chart -> http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/how-computers-boot-up/ .